# From select dropdown to boxes

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce

Is there a way I could make from a drop-down  to a simple box without changing the tags?
Or it there a simpler way to transform it into a radio-button but still keeping the back-end functionality?

This is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I want to do:

[image]

It is a website built using wordpress and woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Probably easier to change to a radio button...

Comment: I tried that, but kinda failed... I couldn't keep the functionality after the user selects one of the options.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/10/inspiration-for-custom-select-elements/), especially the Box select demo which seems quite similar to what you want to achieve. I think that can serve as a foundation for you to tweak it to your liking. Edit : You'll need to add additional HTML code for the method mentioned in the article, it's not only CSS modification since select can't be styled as such.

Comment: It's a bit difficult with woocommerce... I have to be careful what I edit in order to don't ruin something... :)